# react axios два раза выводит данные с сервера

Tags: reactjs

Такая проблема. У меня есть код на ts react, который получает данные сервера с помощью axios. Но при получении данных с сервера в консоль браузера выводится два раза объект, который получили с сервера, но при этом во вкладке сети, он делает один запрос на сервер. Однако, если я вынесу запрос к серверу выше функции App, то выведется один раз объект в консоли браузера. В качестве сервера я использовал fakeapi.

```
function App() {
    async function fetchPosts() {
        const response = await axios.get<IProduct[]>(url)
        console.log(response)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts()
    }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
        Hey
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Возможно ответ тут - https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.2872a8f6-643082bb-4bd958f2-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит у вас двойной "рендер" из-за установленного тега `React.StrictMode` в `index.ts`.

Этот "двойной рендер" выполняется только в режиме "разработке" и помогает обнаруживать случайные побочные эффекты на этапе рендеринга комонентов.

Если дополнительный рендеринг нарушает работу вашего компонента, это означает, что в вашем компоненте есть ошибка (скорее всего) в соответствии с философией команды React.

Для отключения этого режима (что не рекомендуется делать) удалить обертку `React.StrictMode` в вашем `index.ts`